# Hiding empty values in bar plot in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart

How can I hide the x-axis and at the same time shrink the chart where there are no values? The idea is that the chart will expand and shrink depending on the value inputs.

[image]

I want the expected chart will look like this even though the chart will select rows way beyond what is shown:

[image]

Is this possible? I have tried many options without success.

Comment: You want to use name ranges or dynamic ranges in excel and set the range as your data source.

Comment: @lostin I tried your suggestion with Dynamic Ranges. I created a dynamic range and switched referencing to cells with dynamic changes. Nothing happened. Do I need to use OFFSET?

Comment: @lostin I think I found the problem. Excel cannot ignore when the cell is blank,i.e. (="")

Comment: You have spaces in your cell or it is a blank cell ? You can use count function to ignore cells with spaces.

Comment: @lostin With function =COUNTA() right? I tried that following method in https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/

Comment: Use Count() function to hide columns with space values